# Having issue with For-Loop

Tags: android, for-loop

I have to take the text file from SD card in a folder and display them
 in textView. I am using this code

```
if(file!=null){
            File list[] = file.listFiles();

            Log.d("file size>>",""+file.length());

            if(list!=null){
                for( int i=0; i< list.length; i++)
                {
                    Log.d(">>>>",""+list[i].getName());
                    if(list[i].isFile() && list[i].getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
                        myList.add(list[i]);

                        Log.d("myList size>>",""+myList.size());

                        try {
                            FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(list[i]);

                            BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fIn));

                            while ((aDataRow = myReader.readLine()) != null) {
                                aBuffer += aDataRow + "\n";

                            }
                            abc = aBuffer;

                            Log.d("log valuee>>",abc);

                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

abc is the string variable in which I am saving the value of each file but it prints the repetitive data every time loop runs. Other Logs are printing accurate data

Comment: any suggestions sir???

Comment: Where does `aBuffer` come from? It seems that you may not be clearing it in between iterations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`abc` and `aBuffer` are never cleared.

So every time your loop runs, they will just get appended to.

For example, if your first file contains "The quick brown fox", and the second contains " jumps over ", and the third contains "the lazy dog", you'll get

> The quick brown fox
>   The quick brown fox jumps over
>   The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

Instead of

> The quick brown fox
>    jumps over
>   the lazy dog

The solution is simply to set `abc=""` before using it again.
Or maybe `aBuffer = ""`, depending on what you intend to keep there.

As is pointed out by @qbeck in their comment, you may want to use a `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer` instead of String. Since your buffer is going to contain entire files, it may affect the performance.

Comment: Or use `StringBuilder` (or `StringBuffer` if you care about concurrency) instead of `String` in `aBuffer += aDataRow` to avoid unnecessary creation of `String` for every line and clear it at the begining of each iteration.

Comment: Sir, can you plz tell me how can I convert this "abc" string into JSONObject

Comment: @Devraj That's another question entirely. It sounds like you need a JSON parser. Maybe the answers to [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java) will help you.

Comment: can I add this question in this current question too as I am trying something but nothing is happening. :(

Comment: @Devraj No, you should not add it to this question. It is a new issue. You should create a [mcve] of the problem you have now, and ask it as a new question. Good luck!